# Integrated Windows Authentication для PHP под IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, авторизация, iis

Есть интранет-ресурс, написанный на PHP. Работает под управлением IIS6 (FastCGI). Необходима автоматическая windows-аутентификация средствами IIS.

При включении в IIS Integrated Windows Authentication (и отключении Anonymous access), аутентификация работает нормально, но есть проблема. Дело в том, что мое приложение использует для работы SQL Server, который настроен только на windows-авторизацию, соответственно приложение у каждого авторизованного пользователя пытается под этим пользователем подключиться к БД, но не имеет на это прав.

Авторизацию средствами SQL Server по определенным причинам включить нельзя. Требуется в любом случае подключаться к БД с помощью выделенной доменной учетки, аффилированной с Application Pool на IIS.

Пробовали отключать имперсонализацию (fastcgi.impersonate = 0 в php.ini) но при этом пропадает автоматическая аутентификация и наблюдается странная работа браузеров:

- IE открывает стандартный диалог доменной авторизации, но не принимает пароль даже если он на 100% правильный.
- Chrome просто отваливается с ошибкой ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS и всё.
- FF открывает стандартный диалог доменной авторизации и без проблем авторизует меня под моей учеткой и далее я вижу, что все работает как надо (разные учетки в _SERVER["AUTH_USER"] и SQL User).

Как мне обеспечить автоматическую аутентификацию, но при этом всегда использовать выделенный аккаунт для работы с БД?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, у вас проблема с IIS и php при отключении fastcgi.impersonate? В таком случае при чем тут вообще SQL Server?

Comment: Сама автоматическая аутентификация при включенной имперсонализации (олицетворении) работает нормально, проблема становится видна при подключении приложения к SQL Server. Аутентификация мне нужна только для логики приложения, но при подключении к БД должен всегда использоваться один и тот же аккаунт для всех авторизованных по NTLM пользователей.

Comment: При чем тут поведение при включенном олицетворении? Вы же сами пишите - вы его отключили, и у вас все перестало работать. При чем тут SQL Server? Он-то работать не перестал.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что при включенном олицетворении авторизация проходит нормально, но меня не устраивает, что приложение пытается коннектиться к БД под авторизованным пользователем. А при выключенном олицетворении авторизация работает только под Firefox и то - не автоматически, но при этом далее все работает как нужно. Вопрос в том, почему при отключенной имперсонализации перестала нормально работать аутентификация?

Comment: Блин, **ну так и задайте этот вопрос**! При чем тут SQL Server?!

Comment: Я по-моему объяснил при чем тут sql server. Проблема становится видной только на уровне подключения к нему и я врядли смог бы описать суть проблемы без упоминания sql server.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, IE будет принимать пароль если скрипт не будет подключаться к SQL Server?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53600/discussion-between-anton-zikov-and-pavel-mayorov).